# Datatable Select all rows

Tags: sql, linq, datatable

I want to insert into table for specific columns into table using select * from datatable.But it is giving me an array .. is there any way I can get the Insert work.

```
all I want to do is 
Insert into table1 (id,name,status) select * from datatable



query += "Insert into " + tableName.ToLower() + "";

query += "(";
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
        query += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower() + ",";
    else
        query += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower();
}
query += ")";


DataRow[] result = dt.Select();

query += "select * from " + result
```

Comment: Try to generate a statement with a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You Can't use two sql Statements at once like that you have to separate them in two different objects or variables (It's sometimes allowed when you end each by a semicolon ; but not in your case )
try to get each cell value in the row

```
                        query += "Insert into " + tableName.ToLower() + "";

                            query += "(";
                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                                    query += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower() + ",";
                                else
                                    query += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToLower();
                            }
                            query += ")";
                            query += "values ( ";

                            string temQry=query;//you need it more than once

                            DataRow[] result = dt.Select();

                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++){

                               for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++){
                                         if ((j+1)<dt.Columns.Count){
                                           query += result[i].item(j) +"," ;
                                          }
                                           else {
                                             query += result[i].item(j);}
                            }
                                        query=temQry; //recover the query for each new row
```

}

Comment: I am doing the loop through each row now.. as mentioned by you..It takes a lot of time to build the insert if I have more data.. so I was looking to insert directly from datatable

Comment: Well i don't really get what do you mean by lot of time ,yet there is a faster way to copy tables . Read about **SqlBulkCopy** [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Agree but my columns may not be the same .. I need to map them and insert the data accordingly.. Is it possible with Bulk copy.Please provide any samples if u got.. Source may have 8 columns but I got 10 in my destination table.. I have to map them and insert accordingly..

Comment: look if you are worried about the wasted time in copieng you can use Multithreading to do other processes until the copy processes finishes

Comment: can you please let me know if we can do a bulk copy by matching the columns in source and destination tables...column mappings

Comment: look you can do apping using DataMapping in DataAdapter object 
but first you have to declare ADO.net or use OLEDB to create dataAdapters